# Countably many discontinuities in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function such that for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $g_t(y) = f(t,y)$ and $f_t(x) = f(x,t)$ are non decreasing functions. Can we now conclude that the number of discontinuities of $f$ are atmost countable?
Tried to imitate the proof in single variable case but not fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y)=1$ for $x \geq 0$ and $0$ for $x <0$ ($f(x,y)$ independent of $y$) then $f$ is dis-continuous at $(0,t)$ for very real number $t$.